# how to add space in for /f "tokens=*"

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

this is my myfile.txt I want to add space in second column as see the sample

```
ARK,LAR    SNE,QNE,898,ILO,SNE,SNE,LAR,LAR,545
AUS,MNY    P08,TTL,7776,STO,STL,STL,MNY,MNY,567
BOS,MTZ    TNK,SDK,444,PPO,TNK,TNK,MTZ,MTZ,456
```

this is the code I am using

```
for /f  "tokens=* " %%i in (myfile.txt) do call :echo2 %%i %%J %%K %%L %%M %%N %%O %%P %%Q %%R %%S
goto :EOF
:echo2
echo insert ('%1','%2','%3','%4','%5','%6','%7','%8','%9','%10'); >>myfile1.txt
goto :EOF
```

its displaying results , where it should have taken space what I am missing any help is appreciated

Comment: This is not java. Batch probably?

Comment: I don't think there is a %10.. you have to call `SHIFT`. Read this : http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Comment: Well, looking at your code, it's doomed to fail. Your metavariable is `%%i` but you are passing `%%i %%J...` and metavariables are `CASE-SENSITIVE.` `tokens=*` means "put all of the tokens in the first metavariable" Since your posted text doesn't contain `insert('` we can conclude this is your source data. It contains spaces. What do you mean by 'insert space in the second column?' HOW? Show us and indicate clearly what your source data is and what you want as the output data derived from that source, otherwise we're just guessing from a program that doesn't do what you want.

Comment: yes basically I want  to write a batch script in windows

Comment: yes I want to write a batch script in windows which will create myfile.txt file like insert (ARK','LAR SNE','QNE','898','ILO','SNE','SNE','LAR')

Comment: Please show the before and after samples of your text.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (myfile.txt) DO (
 SET "dataline=%%i"
 SET "outline="
 CALL :adddata
)
)>myfile1.txt
GOTO :EOF

:adddata
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=," %%p IN ("%dataline%"
    ) DO SET outline=%outline%'%%p',&SET "dataline=%%q"
IF DEFINED dataline GOTO adddata
ECHO insert (%outline:~0,-1%);
GOTO :eof
```

This should do the job with no practical limit on columns - provided of course that the comma is reliably an end-of-column delimiter.

- For each line in the source file, assign the entire line to
  `dataline` and clear `outline`
- then take the first token, delimited by comma, from `dataline`, quote it,add a comma and append it to `outline`; then set `dataline` to the remainder of the line after the first comma.
- repeat until there is nothing left in `dataline`
- output the text `insert (` + all but the last character of `outline` (which will be a comma) + `);`

Comment: Thanks Peter Appreciated your explaination

Comment: `tokens=1*` --> very nice & useful. +1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to preserve the spaces in the text between the 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> comma, correct? Try this:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1-10 delims=," %%a in (myfile.txt) do (
  >>myfile1.txt echo.insert ('%%a','%%b','%%c','%%d','%%e','%%f','%%g','%%h','%%i','%%j'^);
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off & setlocal
(for /f  "delims=" %%i in (myfile.txt) do (
    set "line='%%i'"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:,=','!"
    set "line=!line:    =    ','!"
    echo(insert (!line!^);
    endlocal
))>myfile1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't exceed 9 variables so your script won't work after the 9th. You can use for /f to  copy each line exactly as the original file like so:

```
for /f  "tokens=* " %%i in (myfile.txt) do echo %%i >>myfile1.txt
goto :EOF
```